# How to fixed left div once scrolling done?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I have filter in left side and right side list there is boxes as I given in below code.

Problem:
Actually I want to fixed left side filter when right list is scrolling right now I'm using `position:fixed;` for that but this is not work as I want. Actually I want like OYO Listing page given below link:-
https://www.oyorooms.com/search?location=All%20Localities%2C%20Delhi&latitude=&longitude=&city=delhi&searchType=&tag=deal_dec_new&coupon=WEROPEN&checkin=18%2F02%2F2021&checkout=19%2F02%2F2021&roomConfig%5B%5D=2&localityId=&showSearchElements=false&filters%5Bcity_id%5D=2&filters%5Btags%5D%5Blist%5D=deal_dec_new&country=India&guests=2&rooms=1

My code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .filter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 25%;
        }

        .filter ul {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .filter ul li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background: #ccc;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .list ul {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            display: flex;
            gap: 20px;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .list ul li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            background: #ccc;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="filter">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>10</li>
                        <li>11</li>
                        <li>12</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="list">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following javascript

```
sidenav = document.getElementsByClassName("filter")[0];
bounds = sidenav.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

    // Max scroll = sidenav height - window height
  if(this.scrollY < bounds.height - window.innerHeight + bounds.top){
        sidenav.style.bottom = "";
    if(this.scrollY > bounds.top){
            sidenav.style.top = "-" + (this.scrollY - bounds.top) + "px";
    }else{
        sidenav.style.top = bounds.top - this.scrollY + "px";
    }
  }else{
    sidenav.style.top = "unset";
    sidenav.style.bottom = "0px";
  }
});
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qxa41s32/

revision after comment
https://jsfiddle.net/otvs7z13/

Comment: there is a issue actually when i added header and footer then its mess how can i fixed that also thank you!

Comment: i fixed it, take a look @RohitVerma

Answer (score 1):

To make a side menu similar to where the link points to, use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed` for `.filter`. Like this:

```
.filter {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Is such a result needed?

```css
.filter {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /*bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 25%;*/
}

.filter ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.filter ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.list ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.list ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="filter">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>10</li>
                        <li>11</li>
                        <li>12</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="list">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>7</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need it like OYO it should be sticky from bottom not from top once all filter scrolled then it should be sticky from bottom, i hope you understand what i explain

Comment: @RohitVerma, oh, sorry. I didn't pay attention to this detail